# Deleted list columns keep coming back - how to permanently delete them?

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-list

I need to remove a bunch of now unused columns from a list.

But somehow they keep coming back.

I've deleted the columns from list and content type (and they returned on both of them). Do I need to delete them anywhere else as well?

It seems like they come back when I update a workflow associated with the list, though I haven't thouroughly tested it. The workflow doesn't use any of the deleted columns though.

They are site columns, but surely it's possible to remove a site column from a list and/or content type, right?

Note that the columns have actually successfully disappeared from the visible list, but they are listed under list settings and when I want to create a new item.

Comment: How often do they come back? Sounds like either a Event Receiver or a Content Type Hub.

Comment: @Christoffer It seems like roughly every 15 minutes the columns come back.

Comment: That do sound like a content type hub timer job that pushes out the content types and recreates "the missing columns". Any administrator you could ask about this? If you are not the administrator, i'm afraid that you can't stop it from happening without creating your own custom content type.

Comment: @Christoffer Can I somehow remove them from the new item dialogue without completely removing them from the list?

Comment: Are you using "Collect Data from a User" in the workflow?

Comment: @jpussacq Do you mean the "wait for field change" action? If not, then no.

Comment: No: Collect Data from a User. Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are having necessary permissions eg. (Site Owner/Site admin) and then trying to perform deletion of columns for a List.
This Issue is related to content type publishing. Your SP environment must be using Content Type Hub features. You can see your content type hub site collection by hitting this url:

https://your_tenant_url/sites/contentTypeHub/

Action Plan:
1. First check your content type name present in List.

2. Visit content type hub URL and go to Site Settings -> Site content type -> Click on your content type -> click on Manage publishing for your content type
3. Here you will see last published details. Refer below screen
   [image]
4. Now Delete the column from this location (viz. Site Settings -> Site content type ->select column -> remove)
5. Republish your content type and wait for 5-10 min.
6. Finally, you can check in your subscriber site to receive updates (Site settings->Content type publishing ) from CT hub and you re done. Enjoy! 
   [image]